# Davinci Resolve 17: burn in metadata of still images using image sequence

Tags: davinci-resolve, time-lapse, metadata

I am producing timelapses from 12 megapixel photos taken with a GoPro, each timelapse with up to 50,000 images.
I rename all JPGs in sequence, e.g. `[00001-49999].jpg` and place them in a single folder.
In the Media tab, if "Show individual frames" of the three-dot menu within "Media Storage" panel is **dis**abled, all images show up as a image sequence and can be added to the Media pool just like that.

My goal is: Using Davinci Resolve's "Data Burn-in" functionality, I would like to display the date of a shot burnt into each video frame on the lower left corner.

In "Data Burn-in" I check "Custom Text1" and in the text field use `%Date Modified` (that is, because for some odd reason that field doesn't work -although it is populated- I use `%Comments` alternatively). The problem is that this metadata seems to be available at Media Pool level only, so that there is only **one** metadata dataset for the whole "Image sequence" instead of many datasets, i.e. one per image.

A workaround is to import thousands of images individually to the media pool, then set still image default duration to one frame. But that makes media asset handling a lot bulkier, especially when talking about several tens of thousands of images.

To populate all single image's metadata I use Exiftool to create a CSV such as

```
File Name,Comments
0001.jpg,02.04.2021 19:57:20
0002.jpg,02.04.2021 19:57:50
...
```

and use "Import Metadata to...".

To create the CSV file noted above use: `exiftool -DateTimeOriginal -d "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" -echo "File Name,Comments" -p "${FileName},${DateTimeOriginal}" *.jpg > metadata.csv`

How do I make Davinci Resolve respect all single image's metadata while still using them as an "Image Sequence" asset?

Comment: I think I saw a thread recently on the BMD forums that mentioned using tokens in fusion text+’s.  I’d try looking into that. I don’t think the data burn window updates every frame for anything other than timecode, but I could be wrong. I know .braw recently added per-frame metadata. That’d be one way to check, if you have access to some.

Comment: I think EDIUS 8 was able to convert series of still images to clips, or at least handle them as if there were a single clip. Back at that time you could download a demo version of the software. Maybe it still works. See also [Setting Still Image Clips as Sequence](https://wwwapps.grassvalley.com/manuals/edius_pro_9_manual_en/Mync/chapter9/chapter_9_l1_9_l2_9.html).